# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'WriteableDraft<Note> | WritableDraft<{}>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am converting my ReactJS / Redux Toolkit app to Typescript. One issue that I am facing is I am not able to get the properties of the state object:

```
const useUpdatedData = (
  setNoteDescription: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>,
  setNoteData: React.Dispatch<
    React.SetStateAction<
      {
        fileName: string
        content: string
      }[]
    >
  >
) => {
  const { note } = useAppSelector((state) => state.notes)
  const { noteId } = useParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (noteId && noteId === **note.id**) {
      const filesData = filesObjectToArray(**note?.files**)
      const filesArray = filesData?.map((file) => {
        return {
          fileName: **file.filename**,
          content: **file.content**,
        }
      })

      setNoteDescription(note?.description)

      setNoteData(filesArray)
    }
  }, [noteId])
}
```

I have highlighted them with **.

Here's what the Interface looks like:

```
export interface Note {
  url: string
  id: string
  public: boolean
  created_at: string
  updated_at: string
  description: string
  files: {
    filename: {
      filename: string
      content: string
    }
  }
  owner: {
    login: string
    id: string
    avatar_url: string
  }
}
```

And here's the initial state:

```
interface NoteState {
  notes: Note[] | []
  userNotes: Note[] | []
  note: Note | {}
  searchedNote: Note | {}
  snackbar: {
    message: string
    type: string
    isOpen: boolean
  }
  forks: number
  deletedNote: string | null
  isSuccess: boolean
  isLoading: boolean
  isError: boolean
  isSearchError: boolean
  isStarred: boolean | undefined
  isForked: boolean | undefined
  isCreated: boolean
  isUpdated: boolean
  message: string | undefined
}

const initialState: NoteState = {
  notes: [],
  userNotes: [],
  note: {},
  searchedNote: {},
  snackbar: { message: "", type: "success", isOpen: false },
  forks: 0,
  deletedNote: null,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  isError: false,
  isSearchError: false,
  isStarred: false,
  isForked: false,
  isCreated: false,
  isUpdated: false,
  message: "",
}
```

Clearly, the id property exists in the interface then why does it say it doesnt?

Comment: You are selecting `state.notes` which is an array and then extracting `.note` from it. Did you mean to do `const note = useAppSelector((state) => state.note)` instead?

Comment: No, actually it's coming from the store:
`
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
    notes: notesReducer,
  },
})
`

Comment: The code was working fine before i converted it to Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`note` can be `Note | {}`, that is a `Note` or an empty object. TypeScript is not letting you access the `id` property since it may not exist.

You can make this work by adding another check `'id' in note`, which will narrow down the type to `Note` and then you can access `.id`:

```
if (noteId && 'id' in note && noteId === note.id) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Is there any other way in Typescript to handle this?

Comment: Instead of `'id' in note`, you can also check for any other property that `Note` contains, like `'url' in note`. Essentially TypeScript needs to know that `note` is not an empty object because according to the type, it can either be an empty object or a `Note`.